# Run PHP code on Window / Tab close with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, web

I need to run this code:

```
<?PHP
  $pin=$_GET["pin"];
  unlink("../users/$pin/host.php");
  unlink("../users/$pin/votes.php");
  unlink("../users/$pin/guest.php");
  rmdir("../users/$pin");
  echo "Session ended";
?>
```

Which is located at `php/endsesh.php`

Basically, when you start a session it creates you a folder with a pin number, and it places a host, guest and votes file.

I need this PHP script to run when the tab is closed, so it can delete all those files (Otherwise I'm just overloading my server with files)

So far I'm trying this with no luck:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert("<?php include("http://musicdemo.hol.es/php/endsesh.php?pin=" . $_GET["pin"]; ?>");
    $.get("http://musicdemo.hol.es/php/endsesh.php?pin=<?php echo $_GET["pin"]; ?>");
    return false;
    return "If you exit this page your session will not end. Please either allow the pop-up, by staying in this page and closing again, or click the link saying 'Close this session'";
}
</script>
```

neither the `alert` or the `$.get` commands work.

Comment: So, basically, you need to execute endsesh.php when the user closes the tab?

Comment: Note: javascript cannot execute php

Comment: @Isaac That is not true. JS can load a PHP page which will cause the server to execute the PHP code.

Comment: I can get it to open a new tab but it will be blocked by the pop-up blocker

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Yes. That is 100% right.

Comment: @krowe and that would be the solution, wouldn't it?

Comment: Even if you get this to work, it doesn't sound like a reliable solution.  The browser can "leave" a page in lots of different ways, and it doesn't always have to tell the page that it's doing so.  It sounds like the *root* of the problem is that you're creating files per session for some reason, and I highly suspect there's a better way to do whatever it is those files do.

Comment: I'm guessing that the best answer is going to be to look for a session. If it doesn't exist then delete the files. To my knowledge, there is no trigger for end of session.

Comment: I hope that's not your production code, I could put anything I want in $_GET['pin'] and cause you a lot of issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onbeforeunload` is a highly secured, sandboxed event.  It's really designed solely to catch people with "are you sure you want to close this window" messages, so I'm pretty sure it doesn't allow more advanced features such as an ajax call.  To do so would open up security holes that allow malicious sites to prevent you from closing the window.

I think doing an ajax call to clean up server side session files is not the appropriate strategy anyway, since the browser could easily crash, laptop could lose power, user could lose network connectivity preventing the ajax call etc.  You can't rely on that ajax call succeeding.

PHP already has very good session handling capabilities via session_start() and the $_SESSION global variable, which already has a built in cleanup feature for expiring old sessions.

If you absolutely must keep your current solution, what I would do is run a cron job every hour, day, week, whatever, that searches for any of your files that haven't been accessed in say 24 hours and deletes them.

Also I should note that taking a `$_GET` and passing it directly to `unlink` is one of the worst, most insecure things you can do in php.  If you have that running on a server right now, **you need to fix it immediately**, since a malicious user could potentially do something like `http://musicdemo.hol.es/php/endsesh.php?pin=../../../../../../etc/passwd`.  if 'pin' is a number, you should at least do something like:

```
<?PHP
$pin=$_GET["pin"];
$pin = (int) $pin; // ensure pin is converted to an integer
unlink("../users/$pin/host.php");
unlink("../users/$pin/votes.php");
unlink("../users/$pin/guest.php");
rmdir("../users/$pin");
echo "Session ended";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks to be incorrect, try:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.get("http://musicdemo.hol.es/php/endsesh.php?pin=<?php echo $_GET["pin"]?>");
    return false;
    return "If you exit this page your session will not end. Please either allow the pop-up, by staying in this page and closing again, or click the link saying 'Close this session'";
}
</script>
```

It looks like your alert line is messing this up.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove alert().
keep $.get.
```

Have you seen the apache logs?

Probably you could have a permission problems `(chmod +x endsesh.php).`

I think i will give a try with exec (https://www.php.net/function.exec).

But before you have to understand if `endsesh.php` is reached.

Comment: javascript is working or has a parse error? Have you check? alert("try"); will work there?